# PHP how to echo during a foreach loop rather than at the end?

Tags: php

I'm quite new to PHP and have been having some trouble with figureing something out. Whenever I use a foreach loop to echo something to the screen, it only echos once the loop has finished. This makes the page loading time quite long.

Is there a way to make it echo as soon as the loop has iterated?

For example,

```
foreach ($a as $k => $v){
    echo $k . " : " . $v;
}
```

I would like it to echo as soon as it's completed one loop rather than at the end.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: this will echo for each execution only

Comment: you want $k value after end of foreach?

Comment: i bet this provided code is not the original, and i bet you are putting a `;` end-of-line sign after the foreach like this
`foreach ($a as $k => $v); {`

Comment: try `ob_flush();` right after your `echo` if this does not work, then refer to the perfectly good answers bellow or to http://www.sitepoint.com/php-streaming-output-buffering-explained/

Comment: Nope, this should echo separately in every loopy cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with output buffering

something like:

```
ob_start();
foreach ($a as $k => $v){
    echo $k . " : " . $v;
    ob_flush();
}
ob_end_flush();
```

but I don't recommend it. You can read more about it on [this site](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

Answer (score 2):

After a bit more searching with a reworded question, I found some information on needing to use flush(); and ob_flush();. Adding them to the end of the foreach loop pushed it to the browser and displayed it after each iteration.

For example:

```
foreach ($a as $k => $v){
    echo $k . " : " . $v;
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop will `echo` on each iteration, though it won't post the result to the screen immediately. You will only see the result once the page has rendered in your browser unless you're doing some stuff with Javascript/AJAX to get it to work differently.

You don't see an immediate result as you would with a desktop/mobile application since PHP needs to build an HTTP response containing the rendered HTML document you've generated with your PHP code, then send that response to the browser, where it is rendered.

Comment: Is there a way to get the page to update as soon as it is echoed, then? Or would there be a better way of printing the information to the screen as soon as it's executed?

Comment: First you need to understand how an HTML page is rendered with PHP. Consult Google or the PHP docs for that. You can use Javascript with AJAX to update the page dynamically by calling certain pages, etc. Though that is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Nice explanation you should just mention [`ob_flush()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ob-flush.php)

Comment: PHP doesn't build HTTP Response. PHP can modify response but it is send to broweser and build by http server. PHP can be also run in CLI and then what? If you use brower then you can flush results to it with ob_flush();

Comment: @Robert I was providing a simplified explanation. I'm not going to delve into the depths of exactly what PHP can and can't do since OP doesn't understand the basics in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In a browser that is calling the php yes you have to wait for the whole page to load and all server executions to complete before the data will be displayed. If you want to speed this up though for testing purposes you can put a break in a loop to stop the loop and go on. Also to see the results one by one as they come in you can run the php file on the server or your computer in terminal/cmd. There used to be a way to do it years ago and you might be able to find a browser and web server combination that still supports the flush command in php for browser quick sends. The problem with this is that the buffers override and don't like being sent out especially with so many more advanced buffers in this day and age.